# herokuにRailsアプリをデプロイ後、使用しているiconが反映されない。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

herokuにRailsアプリをデプロイしました。
しかし、使用しているiconが反映されません。

Material design liteを使用しており`rake assets:precompile`後、herokuにデプロイするとMaterialのCSS/JSはうまく反映されているのですが、アイコンのみ文字で表示されてしまいます。

`bower`を使ってインストールしており、以下のようにvender以下のmaterial-design-iconsのディレクトリへのパスの設定を試みましたがうまくいきません。
    `config/application.rb`
    `config.assets.paths << "#{Rails}/vendor/assets/material-design-icons"`

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

logにはどのようなエラーが出ていますでしょうか？

対象のプロジェクト内で`heroku logs` または `heroku logs --tail`のコマンドでlogを閲覧できますので、まずはエラーを特定してみてはどうでしょうか。

また参考までとなりますが、**Asset Pipeline**に関しては、

- Rails3系 (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#the-rails-3-asset-pipeline)
- Rails4系 (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline)

に説明がありますので、設定を見直してみると良いかもしれません。(注: `config.serve_static_assets`は4.2系から`config.serve_static_file`に変更されています)

ちなみに、Railsプロジェクト以下にある`/vendor/assets/material-design-icons`を指したいのであれば、

```
config/application.rb
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails}/vendor/assets/material-design-icons"
```

↓

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/material-design-icons"
```

となるかと思います。
余談となってしまいますが、変数やメソッドの戻り値/挙動を確認したい場合は`rails console`
で実行してみると良いかと思います。

e.g.

```
$ cd ~/src/github.com/fukuiretu/hoge # hogeは対象のRailsプロジェクト
$ bundle exec rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.4)
[1] pry(main)> Rails.root  => # <Pathname:/Users/fukuiretu/src/github.com/fukuiretu/hoge>
```